# React Native : reload app or force rerender

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, uinavigationcontroller, react-native

In my code after user clicked on a button i want to redirect it to first page (login) page.

i tried to do that with navigator.push  , it works but it still shows the top header and tabbarios in bottom.

How can i just reload the app with one button , or force render index.ios? (rerender root page)

I also want to do same with TabBarIOS. whenever you scroll or go deeper in a tab, when you go to another tab and come back to first tab, it's not rerendering. showing the last status of it.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard seeing without code.

You want to refresh screen, under certain condition ?

If your screen is a component and if you change your component state ( `this.setState()` ), it will change those state value accordingly in your page.

[UPDATE]

Thanks for clarification :

So, in your index render you can do something like :

```
render(){

    if(this.state.logout){//Whatever condition you want to be met.
       return (<Login />);
    }
    else{
      return (<TabBarIOS ... />);
    }

}
```

It should remove the TabBar and show the login.

Comment: Well, in my index.ios i have TabBarIOS. one of tabs is Profile, which renders Profile.js. i have a logout button in profile.js , when logout is pressed first i set the login state to false (usting this.setState), then i need to redirect user to login page which is Login.js , i tried to do it with navigator.push , it works but it still shows TabBarIOS

When app first loads, its checked if you are not logged in it shows you login page. so in profile page when you click on logout, actually i set login status to false. i just need app to be reloaded.

Comment: There is no "reload". I think you should have a index.ios with only the navigator, that can set the route to either login.js or main.js(wich contains a TabBarIOS) This way the TabBar is restricted to main.js and every components in it, the login should not be impacted.

Comment: I had the tabbarios in index that each tab renders a different component. One of them as i said is profile component. In profile component i have the logout button. Isnt there another way to send user to another component when he clicks a button? Navigator.push does that but it still shows the tabbar as i said. Im looking for some alternatives for navigator.push

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the logout button is in profile component not in index. But anyway i try it and thanks for your reply

Comment: Because im already doing that. In idex im checking if the logged in status is false im showing login page otherwise tabbar. But my logout button is in profile page. I can render login page but also tabbarios is shown. I need to get rid of it.

Comment: If your index listen to a store (if you use flux or redux) that contains the information you don't care where the action happend